# S3 bucket not AccessDenied from AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I got the S3 credential (Access Key ID,AWS Secret Access Key) and some bucket name "abc/deepesh" where I have to put the file.
So I configure the AWS CLI.

```
aws configure
AWS Access Key ID [****************XZ6A]: *********
AWS Secret Access Key [****************n7ht]:******
Default region name [None]:
Default output format [None]:
```

Now I tried to access the object:-

```
aws s3 ls s3://abc/deepesh
An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListBuckets operation: Access Denied

aws s3 ls abc/deepesh
    An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListBuckets operation: Access Denied

aws s3 ls 
An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjects operation: Access Denied
```

after getting this response I think that its access issue in AWS side which need to change. but this is not true, because this accessible from ["CyberDuck tool"](https://cyberduck.io/)
Also accessible from Java code using AWS SDK.

So what is the problem, why I am not able to access from AWS CLI.

Comment: Your java SDK might be using some other default access/secret key. Enable console login and go check if you can view s3 buckets using this account.

Comment: No, I am 100% sure, the SDK is using the same credential, also accessible from CyberDuck. My finding is that, the AWS admin created multiple bucket and the credential which shared with me only give access for "abc/deepesh". but how to access this from CLI I don't know.

Comment: Then admin did not give you list bucket privileges. You only have access to files inside of the deepesh "folder". You can use other commands to get objects but cannot use listbucket.

Comment: Yes, You are right.  aws s3 ls s3://abc/deepesh/abc.txt is working.
Thanks.

Comment: n.b. `abc/deepesh` is not the bucket.  The bucket would only be `abc`.